# How to document sub-namespace with JSDoc when using module pattern

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I'm trying to document functions inside a specific module pattern with jsdoc-toolkit where the namespace is defined outside of the module. The functions that get attached to it are inside the immediate invoking function. What I get from the tool output is:

**WARNING: Trying to document isObject as a member of undocumented symbol CORE.**

Here is the simplified version of the code:

```
/**
 * @namespace The framework's top namespace
 * */
var FX = {
  /**
   * @namespace The core framework functions
   */
  core: {
  }
};

(function( CORE, GLOBAL ) {

    'use strict';

    var _isObject;

    CORE.isObject = _isObject = function( object ) {

        if (null === object || (void 0) === object) {
            return false
        }

        return true;

    };

    return CORE;

})(this.FX.core, this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the `@memberOf` tag, which allows you to document what you consider the "parent" or container of an object to be.

```
/** 
 * @memberOf FX.core 
 */
CORE.isObject = _isObject = function( object ) {
    // ...
};
// ...
```

Syntax: `@memberOf parentNamepath`, parentNamepath is the namepath of the containing object.

Comment: I already figured that one out, still I'm waiting to see if there is some other solution

Comment: Accepting because it is only answer and probably will help some1 in a similar situation.